# Updating cordova plugins according to config.xml

Tags: git, cordova, plugins

I work on my cordova project on two machines: macbook and a PC.
When I update plugin on one machine, nothing updates on another after pulling changes. Tracking cordova plugins with git would fix the problem, but it looks really bad. Currently I'm tracking config.xml only.

When I try to execute:
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-my-plugin` it only shows list like this:

```
...
skipping existing file: android-1.png
skipping existing file: android-2.png
cp: dest file already exists: /Users/user/cordova-app/plugins/cordova-plugin-my-plugin/LICENSE
cp: dest file already exists: /Users/user/cordova-app/plugins/cordova-plugin-my-plugin/README.md
...
```

So it ends up with a donkey work for every plugin:

- `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-my-plugin`
- `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-my-plugin@1.2.3`

Does anyone had and solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-my-plugin@1.2.3 --save` - this will put the plugin npm name (or local path, or url) along with version into the `config.xml`.
And then `cordova prepare` will restore the plugin at the saved version.

See https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/platform_plugin_versioning_ref/index.html#saving-plugins for details.

Comment: Thanks, but initially I use `--save` option, so package is saved in config.xml. The problem is: When I update package on one computer, it's not updated on second one with `cordova prepare`.

Comment: How are you updating the package? Is the plugin on npm or Github? What is in your config.xml (related to the plugin)?

Comment: It's github with hash specified `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera-preview" spec="https://github.com/chancezeus/cordova-plugin-camera-preview.git#c6f4aea226f54db4ec4850f3b1d9e9841a0ad426" />`

Comment: So do you first run `cordova plugin add https://github.com/user/plugin#hash1 --save`, then update and push the commit `hash2` to the plugin repo, update config.xml `hash1` to `hash2`, call `cordova prepare` and it does not update to the new version?

Comment: That's correct! Even switching from one fork to another does nothing more than showing info `skipping existing file ABC`

Comment: I got it, thanks for explanation. I think your scenario should be covered by [`cordova plugin add ..\local\path\toPlugin --link`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/#syntax) - note that it requires Administrator privileges on Windows to make a symlink. Although I tried it and it does not update projectRoot\plugins\plugin -> projectRoot\platforms\windows\platform_www so `cordova prepare` still will not result in an updated plugin code in the platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue (keeping installed plugins in sync with config.xml across multiple machines).

I have created a tool - [cordova-check-plugins](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-check-plugins) - which allows you to do this:

```
$ npm install -g cordova-check-plugins
```

In v2.0.0, specifying `--target=config` checks the version of locally-installed plugins against those specified in config.xml, so you can see which locally installed plugins are out-of-date with respect to the config.xml.

To update local plugins to those versions specified in config.xml, use:

```
$ cordova-check-plugins --target=config --update=auto
```

If you want to enforce this, even if the locally-installed version is higher than that specified in config.xml, use:

```
$ cordova-check-plugins --target=config --update=auto --allow-downdate
```

You can check which plugins have updates remotely available, update them interactively, and save updated versions to the config.xml using:

```
$ cordova-check-plugins --update=interactive --unconstrain-versions --save
```

Answer (score 0):

After working with this stuff for a long time, the method working in 100% cases is:

- remove plugins/*
- remove platforms/*
- call `cordova prepare`